# How can I use one font face for normal weight and another for bold on the body?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

I am trying to apply the font 'open sans' to my website.  I would like to use the 'open sans regular' for text that isn't bold and the 'open sans bold' font for text that is bold, 'open sans italic' for italic text, and finally 'open sans bold italic' for text that is bold and italic.  I don't want to set a class but rather just have them apply to the entire website.

Here is the code that I have tried, but it is just applying 'open sans italic' and i think 'open sans bold italic' to everything even when it shouldn't be italic..

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensans';
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensans';
    src: url('opensans-semibold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-semibold-webfont.svg#open_sanssemibold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensans';
    src: url('opensans-italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-italic-webfont.svg#open_sansitalic') format('svg');
    font-style: italic, oblique;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensans';
    src: url('opensans-semibolditalic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-semibolditalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-semibolditalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-semibolditalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-semibolditalic-webfont.svg#open_sanssemibold_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic, oblique;
}
body {
font-family:'opensans';
font-size:78%;
}
```

Here is an example of the issue, notice all font is italic when it shouldn't be: http://www.bbmthemes.com/themes/modular/

Comment: All font is not italic on the mentioned. The problem description is incomplete in other ways too (no HTML etc.), and the poster’s own answer seems to say that the problem was solved, though the logic in the answer is faulty (the order does not matter by the specs).

Answer (score 4):

Ok, I figured out my own question.  There has to be a very specific order for it to work correctly.  You need to define them in this order:

normal
italic
bold
bold italic

So the css would look like this:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensans';
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensans';
    src: url('opensans-italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-italic-webfont.svg#open_sansitalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensans';
    src: url('opensans-semibold-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-semibold-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-semibold-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-semibold-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-semibold-webfont.svg#open_sanssemibold') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'opensans';
    src: url('opensans-semibolditalic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-semibolditalic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-semibolditalic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-semibolditalic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-semibolditalic-webfont.svg#open_sanssemibold_italic') format('svg');
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
body {
font-family:'opensans';
font-size:78%;
}
```

This article helped me to figure it out http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/

Comment: I suspect it's less to do with the order and more to do with the inclusion of both `font-weight` and `font-style` within each `@font-face` declaration.

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways of doing that, by creating various font entries (a little heavier loading and unnecessary) or by applying the font type on the font-weight or font-style.

Various font entries (change the MyFontName value to the name of the new font type you want):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MyFontName';
    src: url('opensans-italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('opensans-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('opensans-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('opensans-italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('opensans-italic-webfont.svg#open_sansitalic') format('svg');
    font-style: italic, oblique;
}
```

Best way (apply the font-style of the font on the CSS you want):

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'opensans';
        src: url('opensans-italic-webfont.eot');
        src: url('opensans-italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
             url('opensans-italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
             url('opensans-italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
             url('opensans-italic-webfont.svg#open_sansitalic') format('svg');
        font-style: italic, oblique; /* FONT STYLE ARE HERE */
    }

p{font-family:opensans, sans-serif; font-style:italic;}
```

Comment: What I am trying to do is have all of the body font be regular, not italic.  I only want text that has the css property 'font-style:italic;' to automatically use the open sans italic font, I want everything that is not italic to use the open sans regular font.  The p tags should all be regular.

Comment: You've done it already, the problem is you assigned the same font-family value to all your font entries.

font-family: 'opensans'; - Assign only one name for each font entry, so you can then match the specific font on the specific element.

Comment: I don't want to have to style every element, the point is that it is supposed to work automatically.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the font family name with different identifiers. I can see you are using the same name for all class. Check below-

Normal

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'opensansNormal';
    // code goes on
```

Bold

```
 @font-face {
    font-family: 'opensansBold';
    // code goes on
```